# Не могу разобраться в тестирование

Tags: java

Не  могу разобраться как создавать тесты.Что нужно прописывать что бы данные корректно брались с той функции которую я создал?

В интернете находил только простые примеры на сложение 2х чисел.Это я понял как делать,но если нужно будет выполнить тест чего то посложнее, например, с циклами с вывод информации на экран то вот это мне не понятно.
Попрошу просто рассказать понятным языком как это сделать.

Comment: Приведите пример своей функции или класса, тогда пару примеров сделать не будет проблем.

Comment: @wigravy
public static void checkLogin(String login) {
                        if (login.length() < 5) {
                System.out.println( "Login is invalid" );
            } else {
                System.out.println( "Login is valid" );
            }

        }

Comment: Такой код как минимум не очень корректный, но я понял суть вопроса)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример с JUnit5. Если хотите проверять именно вывод в консоль, то вот отличная статья - https://www.baeldung.com/java-testing-system-out-println

```
// Класс для проверки логина   
public class LoginService {
        public boolean checkLogin(String login) {
            return login.length() > 5;
        }
    }

// Тесты
public class LoginServiceTest {
    LoginService loginService = new LoginService();

    @Test
    public void correctLoginTest() {
        Assert.assertTrue(loginService.checkLogin("jhondir"));
    }

    @Test
    public void invalidLoginTest() {
        Assert.assertFalse(loginService.checkLogin("jhon"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот тут опять таки я все понял)Спасибо)
то есть мне не обязательно использовать всякие операторы, циклы если я хочу просто без вывода информации?

Comment: Верно. JUnit сам выведет всё в консоль если будут ошибки. Другое дело если вы хотите эти ошибки выводить на стороне клиента, тогда вам нужна валидация данных.

Comment: ну все теперь хоть немного прояснилось,а то сижу на курсах а там 15 минут видео и 3 примера со сложением и все.еще раз спасибо)